# Convert gives an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this query I get Incorrect syntax error "(". Is this the correct way of using CONVERT?

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(mm,[actualclosedate]) AS [Month],
    COUNT([opportunityid]) AS 'Won Opportunities',
    CONVERT(SUM(ISNULL([actualvalue],1)) as numeric (10,2)) AS 'Value'

FROM  [dbo].[FilteredOpportunity]
WHERE [owneridname]= @SalesPerson   
    AND YEAR([actualclosedate]) = @Year

GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm,[actualclosedate])`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use convert you put the type first before the expression:

```
SELECT
DATEPART(mm,[actualclosedate]) AS [Month],
COUNT([opportunityid]) AS 'Won Opportunities', 
CONVERT(numeric (10,2),
        SUM(
                ISNULL([actualvalue],1)
            )
        ) AS 'Value'

 FROM  [dbo].[FilteredOpportunity]
 WHERE [owneridname]= @SalesPerson   
 AND YEAR([actualclosedate]) = @Year

 GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm,[actualclosedate])
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of CONVERT() use [CAST()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx) function.

**Syntax**

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type )
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the correct statement:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(mm,[actualclosedate]) AS [Month],
    COUNT([opportunityid]) AS 'Won Opportunities',
    CAST(SUM(ISNULL([actualvalue],1)) as numeric (10,2)) AS 'Value'

FROM  [dbo].[FilteredOpportunity]
WHERE [owneridname]= @SalesPerson   
    AND YEAR([actualclosedate]) = @Year

GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm,[actualclosedate])`
```